# Rational normal curve as determinantal variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

We work here over complex numbers. Let $\Omega(Z)$

\begin{pmatrix} 
L_1 & L_2 & ... & L_n \\
M_1 & M_2 & ... & M_n\\
\end{pmatrix}

be a $2 \times n$  matrix of homogeneous linear forms
$L_i(Z), M_j(Z) $ in variables $Z_0, Z_1,..., Z_n $ on
$\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ satisfying the condition that
for all $[\lambda, \mu] \in \mathbb{P}^1$ the linear forms
$\lambda L_1+ \mu M_1, ..., \lambda L_n+ \mu M_n$ are linearly
independent.

In Joe Harris' Algebraic Geometry, Exercise 1.25 (p 14) is asserted that
the determinantal variety $\Sigma_1(\Omega) =
\{[Z_0,..., Z_n] : \operatorname{rank} (\Omega(Z))) =1 \} \subset \mathbb{P}^n $, that's the vanishing set of $2 \times 2$ minors of
$\Omega(Z))$ is *rational normal curve*.

I not understand why $ \Sigma_1(\Omega)$ is a rational normal curve.
Recall that a rational normal curve is defined as image of

$$ f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^n,  \lambda \mapsto [A_0(\lambda):...: A_d(\lambda)]  $$

where $A_0,..., A_n \in \mathbb{C}[X_0, X_1]$ are linearly independent
homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$, equivalently
$A_0,..., A_n$ form a basis of of the space of $n$-forms on $\mathbb{P}^1$.

The argument which Harris sketched looks incomplete:
The argument was simply that for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^1$ the equations

$$   \lambda L_1+ \mu M_1 = ... = \lambda L_n+ \mu M_n = 0          $$

determines the unique point $p_{[\lambda: \mu]}$, so we obtain the map
$ f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^n, [\lambda: \mu] \mapsto p_{[\lambda: \mu]}$.
But why then $f$ is given by a *basis of polynomials of degree $n$* on $\mathbb{P}^1$? I agree that $f$ is given as a column of certain adjugate matrix which has homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ as entries. But why they are linearly independent?